# NSDate and NSString cocoa

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate

For my iPhone app I got to convert NSDate object to string, and then convert the string back to NSDate object.. Can someone help me out? thank you!

Comment: Instead of converting the NSDate into a string and then back into an NSDate, you will probably want to keep the NSDate as it is and create an additional NSString object to represent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use to convert from `NSDate` to `NSString`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];
```

Use to convert from `NSString` to `NSDate`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: stringFromDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out `NSDateFormatter` this does exactly this, both directions.

Answer (score 0):

**convert  NSDate to NSString**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

//Optionally for time zone converstions

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];
```

**Convert NSString to NSDate**

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter release];
```